# Means of caching in GWT

Tags: gwt, caching

What is the best way of caching things in GWT. Data retrieved from RPC calls.  I am interested in Data Structures and frameworks available out there, like ehcache.  I am using gxt and have been storing things in the FastMap. What is the load capacity for the FastMap, is this the best way to do things. I know it eventually compiles to javascript and I know in javascript, caching is mainly saved in object literals { key : value } ...Anyone else doing this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're using [gwt-dispatch](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/) with its `CachingDispatchAsync` class to enable caching for GWT. GWT-dispatch is an implementation of the command pattern used for communicating with the server via async calls. It provides a single point for executing those commands where caching can be done. There are several tutorials for gwt-dispatch out there, [this](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2010/03/02/tips-for-using-cachingdispatchasync-with-gwt-dispatch/) might be helpful for your concerns.

Comment: awesome, thanks. I knew of this but was just curious if anyone rolled out their own means implementing caching. Wasn't really concerned with a single point of entry for this caching but I should probably just make use of whats out there. Many Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. Accepting my answer would be really appreciated :).

Comment: Where can I find the license pertaining to the use of gwt-dispatch?

Comment: I don't know where you'll find it (included in the source code?) but the project is inactive for quite a while. Not sure if it is advisable to start using it now.